# Java method references that take different numbers of characters?

Tags: java, methods, retry-logic

I'm trying to apply retry logic to a number of methods. For example, I have method1(String) and method2(int, String) that I would like to retry up to a certain number of times.

I would ideally like:

```
int count = 0;
while (count < MAX_TRIES) {
    try { 
        //run method
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //increment count
        //throw e if count == MAX_TRIES
    }
}
```

inside a method where I could pass in as a parameter method1 or method2. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by `inside method or class`? can you please be more specific

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question, but one way to "pass" a method is to create an `interface`, where there are alternative implementations of a given method, and then one invokes the specific method name.

Comment: There is an existing code base that has a lot of function calls that need to be retried. I just want to be able to pass in those functions whenever they're called to a function that will retry them rather than surrounding these calls with the above retry logic.

Comment: Similar to Command design pattern. You need 2 commands and one command executor.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
public <T> T retry(Callable<T> callable) throws Exception {
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        try { 
            return callable.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            count++;
            if (count == MAX_TRIES) {
                throw(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
retry(() -> doSomething(a, b));
retry(() -> doSomethingElse(a));
```

This simple implementation is not very flexible, and could use better exception handling, though. You could use [a library](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying) to do that (disclaimer: I'm the original author of this library), or at least see how it works and reuse some of its ideas.

Comment: You forgot to `return` a value. When you do, you'd also realize that the loop should be a forever loop, e.g. `for (;;)` or `while (true)`.

Comment: Oops. Yes. Fixed now. Or we could throw an IllegalStateException after the loop. Thanks.